# AWSRekognition - How to separate collections/faces per user account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-rekognition

Thanks for the AWS Mobile SDK, which is a great way to explore and integrate AWS services into our mobile applications.

I am having this issue for several days but have not figured out how to solve yet.

Below is my system diagram:

[image: My system diagram]

1. From app, I make a request to my server, bringing the current `userId`.
2. My server calls `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity()` on each `userId` received at step 1. (specified in `Logins` array) to `AWS Cognito`
3. `AWS Cognito` returns `Identity` and `Token` to my server
4. My server returns `Identity` and `Token` to my app
5. Then my app calls `ListCollections()` on `AWSRecognition.default()` to `AWS Rekognition`
6. Finally, `AWS Rekognition` returns the `collectionIds`

Everything seems good, but I notice that no matter how many different `userId` passed in at step 2., I get the same `collectionIds` returned at step 6.

For ex: user1 (id: 1) creates collection "AllowedGuest". user2 (id: 2) also received "AllowedGuest"

I thought that for each `userId` passed in, I can only get collections and face data that were created by that `userId` only. So, according to example above: user2 (id: 2) should not received collection "AllowGuest".

Why do I get this issue? Is there something that I misunderstand?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is a userID? 
Is it an IAM user of a particular AWS account?

AWS Rekognition ListCollection API returns all collections created by any users of that AWS Account, which explains why you are getting all collections.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_ListCollections.html

Comment: `userId` is the user of my application, not an IAM user

Comment: What matters is AWS credential you used to call CreateColleciton and ListCollection. If the credentials are from one AWS account, then they will return the same collections.